# Forced to click submit button twice

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have Laravel 5.5 a page that has two forms but uses the same controller and method. First form is to cater for initial details but the second form is a search form. My search form works but only if you click the search button twice is there a way I could force to click once to submit that form.

View

```
<form name="FormSearch" id="FormSearch" method="post" action="{!! action(MyController@index',$customID) !!}">
<input type="text" name="searchDets" id="searchDets" value="" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="searchMe" id="searchMe" value= "Search Me"/>
</form>
```

Js

```
$('#FormSearch').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#filterSearchForm').submit();
});
```

I would like my view page to submit once.

Comment: share your filterSearchForm's code

Comment: why did you use preventDefault ?

Comment: I had removed the e.preventDefault but it still requires for you the user to click twice

Comment: If you really must use javascript to submit the form, change the submit button type to button instead of submit. I am not saying that this causes your problem, but would improve readability and intent.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I couldn't find the element with id `filterSearchForm`, so, here is an edit that I made that submits the same form (i.e. `FormSearch`) when you click on it:

```
$('#FormSearch').click(function(e){
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('#FormSearch').trigger('submit');
});
```

I have used the trigger event that is fired which submits the form `FormSearch` when you click on the form `FormSearch`.

Here is it how it works:

```js
$('#FormSearch').click(function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();
  $('#FormSearch').trigger('submit');
});

$("#FormSearch").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('submitted');
});
```

```css
#FormSearch{
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="FormSearch" id="FormSearch" method="post" action="{!! action(MyController@index',$customID) !!}">
  <input type="text" name="searchDets" id="searchDets" value="" />
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="searchMe" id="searchMe" value="Search Me" />
</form>

<p>
  ** Click anywhere on the black area.
</p>
```

I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue and it was due to js version . So please check your jquery.validate's version. 
You can get more information here [submit button twice click issue](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/309)